# vcxproj for x64 settings issue

Tags: x86, x86-64, wdk, win64

I am trying to compile an old source code *(VS 6, WinDDk 7600)*. The source is compiled for **x86** debug version on Windows 10, Visual studio 2019, *WinDDk 7600*. When tried to compile for **x64**(debug, release), I got error.

This `.bat` locations is in `C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\setenv.bat`.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Zee_build, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 07-02-2022 16:15:12.
1>Target Build:
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>  operable program or batch file.
>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(41,5):
  error MSB3073: The command "call \bin\setenv.bat  chk x64 win7
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(41,5): error MSB3073: cd /d C:\Pro\app_build\
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(41,5): error MSB3073: build" exited with code 9009.
1>Done building target "Build" in project "app_build.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: Provide the complete error message.

Comment: Edited Win32  to Win64 <NMakePreprocessorDefinitions>WIN64;_CONSOLE;_AMD64_;_DDK_;_NDEBUG;DBG=0;$(NMakePreprocessorDefinitions)</NMakePreprocessorDefinitions>